# Social Sharing Plugin

Tags: php, ios, html, socialshare

I am looking to make the SMS message sent using the Social Sharing Plugin a clickable link to my app when the SMS message is sent.

Here is what I am using:

```
<a onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(\'Message test\',\'Subject\');">"There is a clickable image here"</a>
```

I want the words "Message Test" to be a clickable link when sent via SMS that opens my app.

Can anyone help?
Where should I place the Myapp:// redirect?